# Can't connect Debezium 0.9.2 to a SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When I'm trying to connect Debezium to my SQL Server database after enable CDC feature, I have this error message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't obtain database name,
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.retrieveRealDatabaseName(SqlServerConnection.java:364),
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.<init>(SqlServerConnection.java:84),
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorTask.start(SqlServerConnectorTask.java:86),
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:47),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:198),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175),
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219),
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511),
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149),
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624),
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748),
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:bce7b974-bac3-4068-b85f-271ba41295e4".,
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2670),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1837),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2257),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1921),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:623),
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$1(JdbcConnection.java:179),
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:734),
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:729),
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:516),
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:391),
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.retrieveRealDatabaseName(SqlServerConnection.java:358),
    ... 11 more,
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:bce7b974-bac3-4068-b85f-271ba41295e4,
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:780),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:836),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:827),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1009),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:997),
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465),
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503),
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975),
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367),
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395),
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379),
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1767),
    ... 22 more,
```

Here is my connector configuration :

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{  "name": "sql-connector",  
    "config": {    
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "database.hostname": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",    
        "database.port": "1433",    
        "database.user": "login",    
        "database.password": "password",    
        "database.dbname": "BDNAME",    
        "database.server.name": "bdservername",    
        "table.whitelist": "bdSchema.TABLE",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",    
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.TABLE"  }
        }'
```

I found a workaround here :

https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/879#issuecomment-438825486

But is it possible to apply it on debezium connector? Is Debezium compatible with Sql Server 2008 R2 because in documentation it's write :

```
The functionality of the connector is based upon change data capture feature provided by SQL Server Standard (since SQL Server 2016 SP1) or Enterprise edition
```

For information, I used Debezium Docker Images 0.9.2 :
- debezium/zookeeper
- debezium/kafka
- debezium/connect

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sébastien

Comment: Hi, Debezium was never tested with SQL Server 2008. I recommend you to try `NotSpecified` value in `authentication` JDBC connection property as it shoud bypass the SSL and verify if Debezium works. Only after that it probably makes sense to work on security layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can I set authentication=NotSpecified into JDBC connection? I tried to put "database.authentication": "NotSpecified" and then "database.history.authentication": "NotSpecified" into connector configuration but I had the same result => Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue when I activated TLS Debug mode.

So I saw that Java 8 use TLS V1.2 by default even if I set any TLS options into JDBC connection properties.

When I tried to connect to SQL SERVER with Java 7, it worked.
After some searches I found that is because Java 7 use this TLS algorithm : 3DES_EDE_CBC.

The workaround is to remove the value `3DES_EDE_CBC` into java.security file in `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` key.

Now Debezium can connect to my Sql Server !

Don't worry I'm not working with a production platform ;-)